# Java reflect method invoke dynamic args

Tags: java, reflection

Can you invoke a java reflect method with a dynamic number of arguments?
Say you have the method updateJsonNode

```
public static void updateJsonNode(String arg1, JsonNode arg2, JsonNode arg3, String arg4){
// Do stuff here
}
```

What i need to know is if you can pass an object array in as arguments or if you are forced to actually invoke the method using the correct types?
Or are you forced to define the method taking the argument (Object[]... objects) and simply cast the objects in the method?

```
Object[] objects = new Object[4];
objects = {"arg1", *JsonNode*, *JsonNode*, "arg4"}
try{
method.invoke(null, objects);
}catch(...){
...
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it with `Object[]`?

Comment: Try it - then share your findings.

Comment: When calling `invoke` on a `Method`, you just pass in a bunch of Objects representing the arguments. There's no reason to cast them, since casting is mostly just to tell the compiler the type of your object